# Issue with script/delayed_job start commad

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fork, jruby, delayed-job

I am getting the following error while running the script/delayed_job start command. I am using Jruby, so i tried with the following command:

```
jruby script/delayed_job start
```

But I get the following error:

```
fork() function is unimplemented on this machine (NotImplementedError)
```

I have googled, as per my observation fork is not implemented for jruby. So I am thinking to run the delayed_job script using rake task.

Can anyone please help me write the rake task which need to run delayed_job script.

Answer (score 4):

Below is the code for run the rake task of delayed job

the path will be \script\delayed_job.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# -*- ruby -*-
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemon_spawn'

RAILS_ROOT = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..'))

class DelayedJobWorker < DaemonSpawn::Base
  def start(args)
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= args.first || 'development'
    require File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'config', 'environment')

    Delayed::Worker.new.start
  end

  def stop
    system("kill `cat #{RAILS_ROOT}/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid`")
  end
end

DelayedJobWorker.spawn!(:log_file => File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "log", "delayed_job.log"),
                        :pid_file => File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'tmp', 'pids', 'delayed_job.pid'),
                        :sync_log => true,
                        :working_dir => RAILS_ROOT)
```

Comment: I am able to run jobs:work rake task. But as per delayed_job documentation, the jobs:work rake task is just for development mode. for production need to use script/delayed_job start. For this reason I am trying to run delayed_job script.

Comment: Could you please let me know is it possible to use jobs:work rake task  for production mode.

Comment: Have  you added the RAILS_ENV=production in your command. The command will be `rake jobs:work RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: I am able to run jobs:work rake task without using the above code also. Could you please let me know is it necessary to use the above delayed_job.rb code in script directory.

Comment: previously I have following code in script/delayed_job

#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize

shall I need to replace this code with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I was using jruby 1.7.3 , rails 2.3.17 & delayed_job 1.8.4 for my legacy rails application.

Command "jruby script/delayed_job start" was not working for my application. I heard jruby 1.7.3 does not support delayed_job. 
So instead of "jruby script/delayed_job start" command , as a workaround I have decided to use rake task "jobs:work" task.

I have added following line in my freezed delayed_job (1.8.4) gem's lib/delayed_job.rb file. 
  require File.dirname(**FILE**) + '/delayed/performable_method'

This has resolved the "performable_method" related errors while running "rake jobs:work" task on my qa & production environment.

Now my delayed job is working perfectly fine on all the environments.
Hope this will help.