# delayed_job gem - NotImplementedError: fork is not available on this platform

Tags: fork, jruby, delayed-job

I am using jruby (1.7.3 or 1.7.9), delayed_job (1.8.4), daemons (1.1.9) gems for my rails 2.3.17 application.

I am trying to start the delayed job server using command:
1. jruby script/delayed_job start

Error:

```
RuntimeError: ObjectSpace is disabled; each_object will only work with Class, pass -X+O to enable
  each_object at org/jruby/RubyObjectSpace.java:173
    daemonize at /home/user/projects/new_central_repo/mml/mml_services/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:39
       (root) at script/delayed_job:5
```

1. To resolve this error, I passed "-X+O" option & ran following command: 
   jruby -X+O script/delayed_job start

This has resolved "ObjectSpace is disabled" error but I am getting following error on local.
Error:

```
NotImplementedError: fork is not available on this platform
              fork at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1880
          safefork at /home/user/.rvm/gems/ext-jruby-1.7.9@jruby179-rails2317/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:11
    call_as_daemon at /home/user/.rvm/gems/ext-jruby-1.7.9@jruby179-rails2317/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:43
        start_proc at /home/user/.rvm/gems/ext-jruby-1.7.9@jruby179-rails2317/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:259
             start at /home/user/.rvm/gems/ext-jruby-1.7.9@jruby179-rails2317/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application.rb:296
               run at /home/user/.rvm/gems/ext-jruby-1.7.9@jruby179-rails2317/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/controller.rb:70
          run_proc at /home/user/.rvm/gems/ext-jruby-1.7.9@jruby179-rails2317/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:197
              call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290
              call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224
  catch_exceptions at /home/user/.rvm/gems/ext-jruby-1.7.9@jruby179-rails2317/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109
          run_proc at /home/user/.rvm/gems/ext-jruby-1.7.9@jruby179-rails2317/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:196
         daemonize at /home/user/projects/new_central_repo/mml/mml_services/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:45
             times at org/jruby/RubyFixnum.java:280
         daemonize at /home/user/projects/new_central_repo/mml/mml_services/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.8.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:43
            (root) at script/delayed_job:5
```

Anyone can help me to resolve this error.

Locally I am able to start my server using "jrake jobs:work" command but I am not whether I can use "jrake jobs:work" instead of "jruby script/delayed_job start".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use delayed_job on jruby because it relies on Fork which is not available in jruby.

Comment: Thanks Richard.

But if I do "jrake jobs:work" instead of "jruby script/delayed_job start", it starts the delayed_job process & also runs my background jobs or entries in the delayed_jobs table perfectly fine.

So for my jruby application is it ok to use "jrake jobs:work" instead of "jruby script/delayed_job start", as I want to use delayed_job gem for my jruby on rails(2.3.17) application

Comment: so others have used rake instead to get delayed_job working on jruby though i haven't personally - i found an alternative solution myself... here's a related so q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676154/issue-with-script-delayed-job-start-commad